# Резиновый блок (Вёрстка)

Tags: javascript, html, css

пришёл с таким вопросом. Хочу сделать резиновый блок, что бы он изменялся как text-area, но только по ширине.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На данном фото открыто приложение телеграмма, но это только для примера

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то речь идёт о возможности растягивать\сжимать блок, как это умеет `textarea`, можно заставить любой (но это не точно) блок растягиваться, благодаря правилу [`resize`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/resize)

```css
.resize {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100px; /* Минимальная ширина, до которой можно "сжать" блок */
  width: 200px; /* Дефолтная ширина, её мы будем видеть изначально, а ограничения будут равны min и max правилам. */
  max-width: 100vw; /* Максимальная ширина, до которой можно "растянуть" блок */
  min-height: 100px; /* для height аналогично */
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden; /* Обязательно свойство */
  resize: both; /* то, что позволит растягивать блок. Подробнее в ответе */
}
```

```html
<div class="resize"></div>
```

Это если речь идёт о "чистых" (без скриптов) решение.

Для более "гибких" решениях, придётся обратиться к скриптам, например [`jQuery UI - Resizable`](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)